# How to download TeamSpeak 3 unto Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: teamspeak

I've been trying to download it from the website, using this link: http://www.teamspeak.com/?page=downloads

I use a 86-bit Ubuntu, but when I download the file, I can't get it to run, and open up. I need someone to show me how to download it, and run correctly.

Comment: Have a look at [This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1996358).

Answer (score 1):

open terminal use the wget command to download

```
wget http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.13.1/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.13.1.run
```

Answer (score 0):

First download your package

```
wget dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.13.4/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64-3.0.13.4.tar.bz2
```

Extract it

```
tar jxf teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64-3.0.13.4.tar.bz2
```

Now change to that extracted directory

```
cd ~/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64
```

Now you can run the server start script

```
./ts3server_startscript.sh start
```